# place grids in terminal in correct positions

Tags: python, terminal

I'm trying to draw up grids on my terminal. The problem is that no matter what I do the grids either overlap entirely or partially. I cannot get the grids to sit side-by-side in a single row for the maximum number of grids which can fit in the currently sized terminal.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
def calculate_player_grid_positions(num_players, max_y, max_x):
    grid_height = GRID_HEIGHT
    grid_width = GRID_WIDTH
    offset = 10  # Horizontal offset

    # Calculate the number of rows and columns of grids that can fit in the terminal
    num_rows = max_y // grid_height
    num_cols = max_x // grid_width

    # Calculate the number of players in a single row
    players_in_single_row = min(num_players, num_cols)

    # Calculate the width of each player's grid area
    player_grid_width = (max_x - (players_in_single_row - 1) * offset) // players_in_single_row

    # Calculate the top-left coordinates for each player's grid
    player_positions = []
    for player_id in range(num_players):
        row_index = player_id // players_in_single_row
        col_index = player_id % players_in_single_row

        # Calculate the vertical offset
        y_offset = row_index * (grid_height + offset)

        # Calculate the horizontal offset for each player
        x_offset = col_index * (player_grid_width + offset)

        player_positions.append((x_offset, y_offset))
    
    return player_positions
```

Here are the variables I have initialized in global scope:

```
GRID_WIDTH = 30
GRID_HEIGHT = 20

# Define the grid offset and border properties
GRID_OFFSET_X = 5
GRID_OFFSET_Y = 6  # Moved down by 3 rows
GRID_ROWS = 20
GRID_COLS = 40
```

Lastly, my max_y and max_x are:

```
max_y, max_x = stdscr.getmaxyx()
```

I know there's a simple way to do this but for the life of me I cannot think of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what was wrong. I was doing indexing based on 0 and 1. However, I needed to start from 1. So I modified the loop to be the following:

```
    for player_id in range(1, num_players+1):
```